# Apple Push Notifications, a little more advanced

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I do know how to configure Push Notifications, but I have no idea where to start when setting it up to send notifications, when some walks past the specific club...

Heres a brief explanation of what I want it to do: Lets say during the night, your out on a night out, you walk past a club, when you walk past the club, if they have any offers on, a push notification will be sent straight to your iphone/ipod.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is much more to this than just the APNS, you will need to add some code to your app to actually track the user location and inform that to a server (where you'll have the offers) and if the user is near one of the offers then will send an APNS to let him know.

Comment: I've sorted it now :) thanks for the suggestion, I have used frameworks provided by a company so up and running!